# tsc command can't compile single file

Tags: typescript, tsc

I found it's weird when I tried to run `tsc Car.d.ts` in a project I clone from github, there was errors from other files in other folder appeared. I thought tsc command should only compile the file I assigned it. I just want to debug the file `Car.d.ts`. Here're some methods I tried so far:

1. I add a very simple file `test.tsx` and run `tsc test.tsx` I get the same error output. So the error isn't due to `import` error since I don't import anything at all in my simple test file.
2. There's no `tsconfig` file in the folder I ran the command. (but there are some in other folders) I guess if the `tsconfig` file in other folders influence my tsc command. So I add a `tsconfig` in my folder to overwrite, with `"files": ["Car.d.ts", "test.tsx"]` specifically. And whenever I run `tsc Car.d.ts`, `tsc`, or `tsc -p .`, I still get the same error output!

The project I clone is https://github.com/foxglove/studio, my aim is to add some new characteristic to it.

Could anyone give some suggestions on this? I don't know why my tsc command isn't smart.

Comment: Maybe you should share what the error is?

Comment: @ChrisHamilton ```../../../../../@types/foxglove__regl-worldview/index.d.ts:19:41 - error TS1110: Type expected.``` Total 7 errors like this. The foxglove project is fine because I run it well before I add my files to it. The project use `yarn` to run, and I guess the error is because I use `tsc` instead. I just want to debug my single file.